# Insert message in JMS queue on Wildfly 27 server

Tags: jmeter, wildfly, activemq-artemis

For testing purposes, I want to insert a message into the queue that is embedded on the WildFly server. I tried through JMeter but I'm not sure how to set it up.

My standalone settings for ActiveMQ Artemis:

```xml
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:14.0">
        <server name="default">
            <security enabled="false" elytron-domain="ApplicationDomain"/>
            <statistics enabled="true"/>
            <security-setting name="#">
                <role name="guest" send="true" consume="true" create-non-durable-queue="true" delete-non-durable-queue="true"/>
            </security-setting>
            <address-setting name="#" dead-letter-address="jms.queue.DLQ" expiry-address="jms.queue.ExpiryQueue" max-size-bytes="10485760" page-size-bytes="2097152" message-counter-history-day-limit="10"/>
            <http-connector name="http-connector" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor"/>
            <http-connector name="http-connector-throughput" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor-throughput">
                <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
            </http-connector>
            <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0">
                <param name="buffer-pooling" value="false"/>
            </in-vm-connector>
            <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor" http-listener="default"/>
            <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor-throughput" http-listener="default">
                <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                <param name="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
            </http-acceptor>
            <remote-connector name="remote-artemis" socket-binding="remote-artemis"/>
            <in-vm-acceptor name="in-vm" server-id="0">
                <param name="buffer-pooling" value="false"/>
            </in-vm-acceptor>
            <jms-queue name="ExpiryQueue" entries="java:/jms/queue/ExpiryQueue"/>
            <jms-queue name="DLQ" entries="java:/jms/queue/DLQ"/>
            <jms-queue name="outgoing_audit" entries="queue/outgoing_audit java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/outgoing_audit"/>
            <jms-queue name="site_node_outgoing" entries="queue/site_node_outgoing java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/site_node_outgoing"/>
            <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory" entries="java:/ConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm"/>
            <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" connectors="http-connector"/>
            <pooled-connection-factory name="activemq-ra" entries="java:/JmsXA java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm" transaction="xa"/>
        </server>
    </subsystem>
    ...
    <socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
        <socket-binding name="remote-artemis" port="5445"/>
        <socket-binding name="ajp" port="${jboss.ajp.port:8009}"/>
        <socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:8080}"/>
        <socket-binding name="https" port="${jboss.https.port:8081}"/>
        <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
        <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9993}"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
        <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
            <remote-destination host="${jboss.mail.server.host:localhost}" port="${jboss.mail.server.port:25}"/>
        </outbound-socket-binding>
    </socket-binding-group>
```

I tried to create a JMS Publisher profile in JMeter but I get Response message:

```
javax.naming.NamingException: javax.naming.NamingException: Invalid broker URL
```

Version of JMeter is 5.5. I added `artemis-core-client-2.28.0.jar` to the `lib` folder.

Is this a good version of JMeter and client or do some other settings need to be done?

[image: jmeter]

[image: wildfly admin console]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the configuration of your JMS Publisher in JMeter is incorrect. You appear to be using the JNDI configuration and library for standalone ActiveMQ Artemis. However, since the instance of ActiveMQ Artemis is embedded in WildFly you need to use a different configuration. Try this:

- Initial Context Factory: `org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyInitialContextFactory`
- Provider URL: `http-remoting://localhost:8080`
- Connection Factory: `jms/RemoteConnectionFactory`
- Destination: `jms/queue/site_node_outgoing`

Then copy the `jboss-client.jar` jar from WildFly's `bin/client` directory into JMeter's `lib` directory, and remove `artemis-core-client-2.28.0.jar`.

Comment: I tried like this but i get the following error:
 
 Response message:javax.naming.NamingException: Expected javax.jms.ConnectionFactory, found org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQJMSConnectionFactory

Comment: Successfully solved I copied jboss-client.jar from wildfly-20.0.1.Final server instead of wildfly-27.0.1.Final, probably problem with javax and jakarta packages, thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the following provider URL:

```
http-remoting://localhost:8080
```

or alternatively:

```
tcp://host:8080?httpUpgradeEnabled=true
```

More information:

- [helloworld-jms: Helloworld JMS Example](https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/tree/main/helloworld-jms)
- [HelloWorldJMSClient.java](https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/blob/main/helloworld-jms/src/main/java/org/jboss/as/quickstarts/jms/HelloWorldJMSClient.java)

by the way you can use the code from the `HelloWorldJMSClient.java` in [JSR223 Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy), it will give you more flexibility and better understanding regarding what's going on under the hood.

In general having system under test and JMeter at the same machine is not the best idea because both can be very resource intensive and it will be hard or even impossible to identify the bottleneck

Comment: For http-remoting  Expected javax.jms.ConnectionFactory, found org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQJMSConnectionFactory

For tcp Response message:javax.naming.InvalidNameException: WFNAM00007: Invalid URL scheme name "tcp"